# Rails Test DB populates after setting ActionMailer defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer

I set up `ActionMailer::Base defaults` in my project, something like this:

```
class DirectorMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: Director.pluck(:email)
end
```

When I try this on `development` environment, runs successfully because I already have Directors in my Database. The problem occurs when I run my tests, because ActionMailer defaults loads before that I fill my test database, and is set with an empty array. I got the following error:

> ArgumentError: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.

Is there a way to reload `ActionMailer::base` defaults from my tests? Or should I set `to` param in each `mail` methods?

Comment: Finally, I have decided to set `to` param in each `mail` method, in order to get the latest `Director` emails array, but the question remains unanswered, so I will keep it open until I find a workaround for this.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Looks like we have been unconventional ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solve your problem of ActionMailer loading before you have records in your db

```
before do
  Director.create(email: "admin@example.com")
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []  
end

after do
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
end

it "..." do
  # perform your test
end
```

> [This blog post](http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/how-to-write-rspec-mailer-tests/) was used to help answer this. Could be useful to you as well

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work, `ActionMailer` still load `defaults` before run my tests. Also, I already have set `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` in my `test.rb` environment file, but I try this anyway...